# Delete files that are not in the installer

Tags: nsis

### Problem statement

Assume there is a folder hierarchy like this:

- `root`

  - `libs`
  - `models`
  - `classes`
  - `images`

This hierarchy exists in an already installed installation and in a new NSIS installer, intended to update that existing installation.

NSIS will replace any files within this hierarchy that have been changed, so *e.g.* if there are models `a.stl` and `b.stl` in the installation directory at `root\models` and there are also `a.stl` and `b.stl` packaged in the installer at `root\models`, then both `a.stl` and `b.stl` will be updated.

However what if `a.stl` and `b.stl` exist in the installation directory and only `c.stl` is packaged in the installer? Then the result in the installation directory after running the installer will be `a.stl`, `b.stl` and `c.stl` all sitting in `root\models`, despite `a.stl` and `b.stl` possibly being outdated.

### Question

Is it possible to set a policy for NSIS on how to deal with files that are part of the target directory hierarchy, but do not exist in the installer package?

This can be achieved by using the `Delete` or `RMDir` commands, of course, however I was wondering if this was necessary or if there was possibly some flag to specify the desired behavior.

I think essentially I am looking for something along the lines of `SetOverwrite`, but for directories (?).

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your installer include all relevent files (a.stl, b.stl, c.stl, etc), so that you can insure that they are all updated?

You could rename the target directory if it exists.  Perhaps even create a sub folder  to store old/replaced versions?

-tjh

Comment: "

Why not have your installer include all relevent files (a.stl, b.stl, c.stl, etc), so that you can insure that they are all updated?" -because it does work for changes, but not for removal. Maybe my formulation was poor, causing an XY problem. The term "outdated" in my post meant, that *e.g.* `a.stl` needs to be flagged for removal. It is outdated, in the sense, that the file is no longer needed. So I was wondering, if I can flag such files for deletion via NSIS installer, *e.g.* remove `a.stl`, leave `b.stl` unchanged and add a new `c.stl` to the folder.